# How to assign function to selector switch?

Tags: javascript, html

I used this selector switch in my html:

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
```

I need to assign 2 functions to the ON & OFF position.
ON position : send a message to arduino yun server : auto_on
OFF position : send a message to arduino  run server : auto_off

something similar to this I used but with an onclick action on a button:

```
function autoon()
    {
        $('#content').load('/arduino/auto_on');
    }
function autooff()
    {
        $('#content').load('/arduino/auto_off');
    }
```

I don't think you can use a onclick event on the slider switch, so I'm wondering how to do this?

Comment: You can listen for click events on almost anything. Here it seems that your "slider switch" is constructed using a `<div>`. You certainly can use onclick events on divs.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
<div class="onoffswitch" onclick="toggleSwitch()">
  //switch slider content
</div>
```

And in your script :

```
var intitalSwitchState=true; signifies on;

function toggleSwitch()
{   
    intitalSwitchState=!intitalSwitchState;
    if(intitalSwitchState)
        $('#content').load('/arduino/auto_on');
    else
        $('#content').load('/arduino/auto_off');
}
```

Comment: Thx for answering... I tried this code but it still isn't working. I don't get any message to my arduino. There are several buttons in my html later on and they are all working fine.